# Errors when trying to update ruby gems from 2.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to set myself up on a mac to learn Ruby on Rails, however I seem to be having some problems. If I try to run commands such as ./script/server, i get this:

> Rails requires RubyGems >= 0.9.4 (you have 0.9.2). Please `gem update --system` and try again.

When I run "gem update.." I get this:

> Updating RubyGems...
>   Attempting remote update of rubygems-update
>   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
>       Permission denied - /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/rubygems-update-1.3.0.gem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

got it.

sudo gem update --system

Answer (score 0):

Starting with El Capitan, Apple prevents user applications to modify `/usr/bin` for security reasons. So better install/update rubygems in the recommended folder, `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo gem update -n /usr/local/bin --system
```

(recommendation taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39928447/1033581)