# Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/update_rubygems

Tags: rubygems

When I execute on osx El Capitan:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

I got the error:

```
Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/update_rubygems
```

Comment: I have the same problem since upgrading to El Capitan :/

Comment: Oldish thread, but I did not want to go the 'workaround-way' by installing Homebrew. By adding it to your local user, it removes the need for sudo, and issue with permissions are resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32253142/731782

Comment: `sudo gem update -n /usr/local/bin --system`

Comment: this works for me

Comment: I needed to use the absolute path `/usr/bin/gem` to ensure the Apple-installed rubygems is updated. Run `sudo /usr/bin/gem update -n /usr/local/bin --system`. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46662080/67834

Answer (score 85, accepted):

ended up installing ruby via homebrew. Install homebrew first:

http://brew.sh

then execute

```
brew install ruby
```

after that it worked flawlessly. It has something to do with the native ruby installation.

Comment: Hi MarcDK, will you explain what this actually does?  I'm having the same issue as yongfong zhang.  If we try your solution, will the **sudo gem update --system** command work from then on?

Comment: This worked for me, but I don't see it as the 'correct' solution, just a workaround. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Had same issue, did this and it worked. Not sure why my gem stopped working, maybe because I got a new computer

Comment: Had to fix permissions first _ Instructions found here http://digitizor.com/fix-homebrew-permissions-osx-el-capitan/  after that, it worked.

Comment: It gives below error in macOS 10.12 (Sierra)
Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.

Comment: When I try brew install ruby, it prompts me this error `Warning: ruby-2.2.1 already installed, it's just not linked`

Comment: I tried to `brew doctor` then `brew update` before `brew install ruby`

Comment: In my case on Mac, I also had to add the new installation to the PATH. According to the installation output: "If you need to have ruby first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc"

Answer (score 34):

If you're having issues installing a specific gem after installing ruby through Homebrew (as advised above), try the following:

`sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin GEM_NAME_HERE`

Found this thanks to user endoplasmic on this issue thread: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1768

Comment: this also worked for me for installing `jsduck`. Although i have no idea why

Comment: This works even with native Ruby installation. Nice work.

Comment: Is there a way to make this the default path for gems so that I don't have to type in `-n /usr/local/bin` every time I want to install / update any gems?

Comment: @MatthewDavis you can change the default path permanently by `echo "gem: -n/usr/local/bin" >> ~/.gemrc`

Answer (score 23):

Starting with El Capitan, Apple prevents user applications to modify `/usr/bin` for security reasons. So just install/update rubygems in the recommended folder, `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo gem update -n /usr/local/bin --system
```

Answer (score 14):

This is an 'issue' (Apple calls it a feature) of 10.11. Basically, you can't modify `/usr/bin` in 10.11 (not even as root (`sudo su -`), there are a number of other folders that also *cannot* be modified).

If you run `ls -l /usr/bin` you will notice that permissions are `555`, or `r-xr-xr-x` (no write access). You cannot change these permissions using `chmod`.

This feature has the slightly incorrect name: 'rootless'. Apple says it is a security measure:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really

You can revert the feature using this gist:

https://gist.github.com/djtech42/7233c602fda912d96fdf

```
#!/bin/bash
#Beta 4 to Final Public Release (Must be run in Recovery Mode)
csrutil disable

#Beta 1-3
sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0";sudo reboot
```

P.S. Some users say this doesn't work, and that you must boot into recovery first, as they do here:

https://www.macbartender.com/system-item-setup/

I'm not recommending you do that. The best solution, is to just install `ruby` (and almost anything else) through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), since you still have write access to `/usr/local`, until Apple decides that is too insecure ...

Answer (score 1):

---

For those that are still having this issue, basically it was a security upgrade that Apple release in the new OSx. It's a System Integrity Protection which is basically a "rootless" security system. Follow these steps to disable:

http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/

**Take Note** This should only be done if you understand what you are doing and why!

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem when upgrading cocopods, my operating system is macOS Sierra , ruby ​​version is 2.0.0.The following way to solve my problem.

1. Through the homebrew upgrade your ruby version.

   `brew upgrade ruby`
2. If you fail to update ruby, this link can help you.

   https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/49895

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple rubygems installs (say from homebrew, rbenv, rvm), to target the update to the default Apple-installed rubygems you may need to use the absolute path `/usr/bin/gem` to ensure this specific rubygems is updated:

```
# Note the absolute path to /usr/bin/gem:
sudo /usr/bin/gem update -n /usr/local/bin --system
```

Answer (score -2):

I do have this problem when I try to uninstall and reinstall cocoapods. After searching, I found the solution is temporary disable the System Integrity Protection then Re-enable System Integrity Protection when works done.

Here are the steps.

1) Reboot your MAC and hold down Command+R until you see the Recovery Mode screen boot up.

2) In this Recovery Mode, look at the top file menu 'Utility' and select Terminal to open the Terminal

3) Enter this command below

```
csrutil disable / reboot
```

Your Mac will reboot now, once it reboot to normal screen, you can check to ensure you have disabled the System Integrity Protection by open the Terminal again and enter the following code

```
csrutil status
```

Now you can carry out the task you want to carry out.

4) Re-enable System Integrity Protection
Once you have your works done, it is STRONGLY recommended that you Re-enable the System Integrity Protection

5) Reboot your Mac to Recovery Mode again. (Hold down Command+R key)

6) Open Terminal when you are in the Recovery Mode screen

7) Enter the following code

```
csrutil enable /reboot
```

Again, to ensure you have Re-enable the System Integrity Protection, after reboot, use the Terminal to check using

```
csrutil status.
```

Hope this help anyone who have the same issue.