# cocoapods, Gem::FilePermissionError

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods

I am on Mac version 10.11.3 OS X El Capitan
I am facing following error while updating cocoapods to latest version.

> You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

[image]

I also tried:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -pre
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/update\_rubygems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015875/operation-not-permitted-usr-bin-update-rubygems)

Comment: Your comment seems to link to a different problem. I already posted an answer here with a relevant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with El Capitan, Apple prevents user applications to modify `/usr/bin` for security reasons. So just install/update rubygems in the recommended folder, `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin --pre
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permissions to install `gems`. You had to use `sudo` before so now your permissions aren't correct.

**Easy solution:**

Run this command with `sudo`:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -pre
```

**Better solution** - install cocoapods for this user only:

```
gem install --user-install cocoapods -pre
```

**Another solution** - fix your permissions:

```
sudo chown -R YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_GROUP ~/.rvm
sudo chown -R YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_GROUP ~/.gem
```

or

```
sudo rvm fix-permissions YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_GROUP
```

Comment: @Faiz Fareed Did it help?

Comment: sorry sir, nothing works among above commands, I tried each & Every. . .

Comment: @Faiz Fareed Every time you get the same error? Even with `sudo`?

Comment: I tried each above mentioned command & every time getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed the beta version, I don't recommend installing with

> sudo gem install cocoapods -pre

if you use -pre you gonna install the beta version, Instead, use

> sudo gem installcocoa pods

Your main problem is that, and you didn't use sudo to give the necessary permissions.