# Ruby installed but sass won't install

Tags: ruby, macos, sass, macos-sierra

I am trying to make my sass work, it was working fine but its has been a while since i worked on it, so today i wanted sass to watch my folder but that watch command didn't work. So i tired to check ruby version by 
`ruby -version` and i got reply

> ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
>   -e:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method`rsion' for main:Object (NameError)

But when i do `gem install sass` it gives me error

> While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

If i am not wrong, its telling of permission but i am the admin and i tried same command with sudo

Comment: Have you tried `gem update --system`? (Try it with `sudo` if doesn't wok otherwise)

Comment: @cema-sp after running it, it produce this error `sudo: update: command not found`

Comment: Try `sudo -- gem update --system`

Comment: @cema-sp `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/update_rubygems` now this is error i get.

Answer (score 2):

The first error you're seeing:

> ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16] -e:1:in ': undefined local variable or methodrsion' for main:Object (NameError)

is because you are running the wrong command. If you run `ruby -v` or `ruby --version` (note the **two** hyphens), you will see:

> ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]

The error message you were seeing is because ruby can take the command line flag `-e` to run code directly from the command line:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts "Hello world"'
Hello world
```

So by running `ruby -version` (note the **one** hyphen), the ruby interpreter tries to evaluate a variable/method named `rsion` and throws an error.

As for your actual error of installing gems, this is caused by having enabled rootless system integrity protection (on Max OSx). You can either disable the protection, as outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33015875/1954610), or install ruby via RVM/RBenv to avoid needing sudo permissions for gem installation.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer but i still get the error `While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory`

Comment: What did you try? Did you disable rootless system integrity protection? Did you install ruby via `brew`, or `rvm`, or `rbenv`? Are you running commands with/without `sudo`?

Comment: I followed the link u [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015875/operation-not-permitted-usr-bin-update-rubygems) and then tried running `brew install ruby` but it said to unlink sylink, and gave me a command which i did and after that i could run `bew install ruby` nd after that i tried running `gem install sass`. Don't know what is `rvm` or `rbenv`

Comment: You will need to properly explain your environment, steps taken so far and error messages. What do you mean by "unlink syslink"? I still don't know if you're using `sudo`. What is the output of `which ruby` and `which gem`? Could you [do a little research](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x) and try installing a non-system ruby to avoid this issue? If you're still stuck after having attempted the aforementioned solution thoroughly, please open a new SO question with more information.